# Unsetting a background value for a:visited vs a:link

Tags: html, css, background, hyperlink, visited

I've just wasted an afternoon figuring out that the `a:visited` selector in CSS has all attributes disabled apart from a handful that are directly related to colour (see here: http://www.impressivewebs.com/styling-visited-links/ ).

Anyway, I'm wondering if it's possible to unset an attribute set for `a:link`? I have an `a:link` selector that fills in the background with a CSS gradient, but it would be nice if this could go grey for `a:visited`.

According to the new implementation, you can set `background-color` for `a:visited`, but unfortunately this gets overridden by the `background` attribute for `a:link` because `a:visited` can't use `background` now.

All I'd like to do is unset background for `a:visited` so that `background-color` is used. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

use a instead of a:link for background color

see fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/amdorra/7WQYt/)

```
a{
    background: green;
}
a:visited{
    background: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your hyperlink a display style of inline-block

```
a{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red; 
  //this becomes the default bgcolor; override it in subsequent pseudo state styles
}
```

This allows you to specify background colors for your hyperlinks.

You have to normally specify the styles for hyperlinks in the following order

- **a:link** - a normal, unvisited link
- **a:visited** - a link the user has visited
- **a:hover** - a link when the user mouses over it
- **a:active** - a link the moment it is clicked

In this order the visited link style overrides the normal link style. So, your css for visited will be applied after you click the link.

Comment: If I set display to `inline-block` it messes up the formatting for those `a` tags. They're `block` UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you declare `a:visited` **after** the `a`. Otherwise the `a` will overrule it.

```
a {
   background: #ff0000;
}
a:visited {
   background: url( none );
}
```

Comment: But I don't think you can set `background` for `a:visited`? That's the problem.